# Querying Git status with Subprocess throws Error under Linux

Tags: python, git, command-line

I want to query the status of the git repo using python. I am using:

```py
subprocess.check_output("[[ -z $(git status -s) ]] && echo 'clean'", shell=True).strip()
```

This works fine on MacOS. However, on Ubuntu Linux I get an error message:

```py
{CalledProcessError}Command '[[ -z $(git status -s) ]] && echo 'clean'' returned non-zero exit status 127.
```

I went into the same folder and manually ran

```sh
[[ -z $(git status -s) ]] && echo 'clean'
```

and it works fine.

I further ran other commands like

```py
subprocess.check_output("ls", shell=True).strip()
```

and that also works fine.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `shell=True`, `subprocess` executes your command using `/bin/sh`. On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is not Bash, and you are using Bash-specific syntax (`[[...]]`). You could explicitly call out to `bash` instead:

```
subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", "[[ -z $(git status -s) ]] && echo 'clean'"]).strip()
```

But it's not clear why you're bothering with a shell script here: just run `git status -s` with Python, and handle the result yourself:

```
out = subprocess.run(['git', 'status', '-s'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
if not out.stdout:
  print("clean")
```